# Tag merging: "Star: and "Stars"

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-synonyms

It seems that `star` and `stars` are two separate tags and there's not good reason for them to be so, especially when the latter is only used 4 times. I suggest to merge both into `star`.

Comment: Instead of opening up a new meta question for each and every minor change of a tag, then I suggest to just write a new answer [here](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/175/2451) that people can vote up or down. (Of course this is formally not a synonym, but that besides the main point.)

Comment: Note that the opposite of this question (v1) has recently been proposed [here](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/4677/2451).